# How to encrypt or hide parameters of URL?

Tags: php

Sample URL:

```
file.php?foo=bar
```

index.php will send encrypted variables `?foo=bar` to `file.php` and here vars will be decrypted.

Its possible to hide or encrypt vars?

i have form:

```
<form id="add">
<input type="text" name="v"/><br>
<input type="text" name="o1"/><br>
<input type="text" name="o2"/><br>
<input type="text" name="o3"/><br>
<input type="text" name="o4"/><br>
<input size="1" type="text" name="good"/>
<input id="btn" formaction="add.php" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: -1 this needs more information about what you want to do. Until then, providing answers to this question is a wild goose chase.

Comment: You can't, but you can encrypt the information passing to server.

Comment: Removing my vote but I still don't understand - who do you want to hide the variables from, the user? Why do you need to hide them?

Comment: adding my vote for the same reason. also voting to close as a pointless question

Comment: how are the form, index.php and file.php are connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use post:

```
<form id="add" method="POST">
```

Comment: That's it really? You send us the from way by talking about encrypted/decrypted. New time please don't guess about the solution, just explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hide them from the user? No. Not if they are used in unencrypted form on the client side at any point.

But hide them from potentially malicious third parties? Yes. Use SSL/TLS, a.k.a. [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https).

Comment: unencrypted form? so how to encrypt form?

Comment: @Ilya please add more detail about what you want to do.

Comment: You can hide them from the browser by using POST or PUT but it all depends on what you're using it for. Easiest way to encrypt the data is with SSL (https) as jordan has mentioned

Comment: Please review the link in my answer, or look for some resources on HTTPS in your native language. Encryption in the browser is a very old problem that you should not try to solve yourself--use existing standards (SSL/TLS) and trust that those solutions work.

Comment: Yes you can hide it from the user. HTTPS does not help here.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no point in encrypting form values.

You are probably under impression of some sort of delusion.

Either leave your form unencrypted or explain, **why** do you need to encrypt it - and get an explanation, why it is absolutely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Can be encoded but can't be fully hidden, [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode) then [base64_decode()](http://php.net/base64_decode)

Comment: base64 encoding is completely worthless for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way encryption in php like [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php), [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) etc that will hide parameter values to be readable but these are not bullet proof.

Comment: base64 encoding is completely worthless for the purpose.